# Maximum likelihood estimator of a uniform distribution $U(\theta,k\theta)$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

So pretty much what's the maximum likelihood estimator of a uniform distribution $U(\theta,k\theta)$ with $k>1$? I have tried a lot of methods but I can't get the answer right. With known k.

Comment: (Assuming everything is positive) If you know $k$ in advance then I would guess it could be something like $\hat \theta =\max(x_i)/k$.  If you do not know either $k$ or $\theta$ then they could be something like $\hat \theta = \min(x_i)$ and  $\hat k = \max(x_i)/\min(x_i)$.  You want to maximise the density on the support, so minimise the width of the support, and you might want to use indicator functions

Comment: Yeah both $\hat{\theta}=\frac{x_{(n)}}{k}$ and  $\hat{\theta}=x_{(1)}$ don't work.

Comment: How do you know $\hat{\theta}=\frac{x_{(n)}}{k}$ does not work?  What gives a higher likelihood?

Comment: Because if $x_{(1)}<\frac{x_{n}}{k}$ then $\hat{\theta}=\frac{x_{n}}{k}$ wont work.

Comment: There is no global maximum of the likelihood function $L(\theta)=f(x_1,\dotsc, x_n; \theta)$ and this can be shown by basic calculus, where $f(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)=f(x_1)\cdot \dotsc \cdot f(x_n)$ is the joint PDFof an IID sample of $\mathcal{U}(\theta, k \theta)$ RVs.

Comment: If $x_{(1)}<\frac{x_{(n)}}{k}$ then necessarily the likelihood of this data is zero. Thus any theta would be equally a candidate for the MLE.

Comment: I think that Henry is correct about this, assuming $k$ was fixed.

Comment: Why if $_{(1)}<\frac{x_(n)}{k}$ then necessarily the likelihood of this data is zero

Comment: Because then either $x_{(1)} \leq \theta$ or $x_{(n)}/k \geq \theta \iff x_{(n)} \geq k\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parameter space for $\theta$ is $(0,\infty)$, let $L(\theta; x_1,\dots, x_n)$ be the likelihood function of a sample of $n$ $\mathcal{U}(\theta, k \theta)$ IIDRVs. Then,
$$L(\theta; x_1,\dotsc, x_n)=f(x_1,\dotsc, x_n; \theta)=f(x_1;
\theta)\cdot \dotso \cdot f(x_n; \theta)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{\theta(k-1)}\right)^n \mathbb{1}_{\theta \leq x_1 \leq k \theta}(x_1) \cdot \dotso \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\theta \leq x_n \leq k \theta}(x_n)$$ 
$$=\left(\frac{1}{\theta(k-1)}\right)^n \mathbb{1}_{x_{(1)} \geq \theta} \mathbb{1}_{x_{(n)} \leq k\theta},$$
so $L(\theta;\cdot)$ is $\neq 0$ only on $[x_{(n)}/k, x_{(1)}]$, where $x_{(1)}$ is the minimum of $x_1,\dotsc, x_n$ and $x_{(n)}$ is the maximum.

We just need to show that $L$ is decreasing in $\theta$ on $[x_{(n)}/k, x_{(1)}],$ and then it follows $\hat{\theta}=x_{(n)}/k$ is the MLE.

Comment: We must have $\frac{x_{(n)}}{k} \leq \theta \leq x_{(1)}$. Otherwise what happens? That would mean that some of the data lies outside of $[\theta,k\theta]$, which is impossible! We would assign a likelihood of zero to such a sample. Therefore we must search for our MLE within said range.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Okay, it is not clear to me why the larger parameter space is problematic still, but I will edit my answer to include the restricted space. The OP can clarify what space they wanted to take the MLE over.

Comment: In maths I'd say $L(\theta) = ((k-1)\theta)^{-n}\mathbb{I}_{x \in [\theta, k\theta]^n}$

Comment: @NapD.Lover The parameter space is not restricted. It is $(0,+\infty)$. And the likelihood function is not the same for all $\theta$. It depends on samples. If $\theta<x_{(n)}/k$ or $\theta>x_{(1)}$, the likelihood function is zero.

Comment: @NCh I have edited it finally. Let me know what you think.